# Cuda: Error 11: invalid argument en cudaMemcpy

Tags: c, cuda

Tengo tres ficheros, main.c donde está el código principal, kernel.cu donde están las funciones con llamadas de cuda y kernel.h con las cabeceras.

En main.c tengo:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
   bands = 19;
   float *out_c;
   float *v = (float *) malloc (bands * sizeof(float));


   for (j = 0; j < bands; j++){
        v[j]= j;
   }

   reservar(out_c, bands);
   copiar(out_c, v , bands);

   //Código

   liberar(out_c);

return 0;
}
```

En kernel.cu:

```
void reservar(float *out_c, int bands){
    cudaMalloc((void**)&out_c, bands*sizeof(float));
    check_CUDA_Error("ERROR EN cudaMalloc de out_c");
}

void copiar(float *out_c, float *v, int bands){
    cudaMemcpy(out_c, v, bands*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    check_CUDA_Error("ERROR EN cudaMemcpy de out_c");
}

void liberar(float *out_c){
    cudaFree(out_c);
    check_CUDA_Error("ERROR EN cudaFree de out_c");
}
```

Cuando quiero copiar v en out_c es cuando sale el error de argumento inválido. Al imprimir la dirección de memoria en la que se guarda out_c cuando está en la función copiar, el valor es nulo. ¿Se pierde la reserva de memoria cuando vuelve al código principal desde reservar? ¿Por qué aparece como argumento inválido?

Comment: El error te lo da **al ejecutar**, ¿ cierto ? No es un error de compilación. Y aun diría mas ... ¿ estás usando un compilador de microsoft ?

Comment: Sí, el error es en ejecución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Al imprimir la dirección de memoria en la que se guarda out_c cuando está en la función copiar, el valor es nulo.

Lo de que sea nulo es un comportamiento indefinido. Supongo que estarás usando un compilador de microsoft, que tienen la *funcionalidad* de inicializar todas las variables con `0`. En este caso, es útil para localizar el error.

Por definición, el valor de una variable **sin inicializar** es algo indefinido. Algunos compiladores las inicializan a `0` ... y otros las dejan con valores aleatorios. Ambos casos son correctos.

> ¿Se pierde la reserva de memoria cuando vuelve al código principal desde reservar? ¿Por qué aparece como argumento inválido?

Aparece porque estás pasando un argumento **por copia**. Cualquier modificación que hagas en un argumento pasado por copia **es local a la función**, y se pierde al salir de esta.

También, cualquier intento de obtener la dirección `&` de un argumento pasado por copia, devolverá la dirección **de la copia**.

Vamos a cambiar un poco tus funciones, para recibir los argumentos **mediante punteros**: es decir, usaremos directamente **la dirección** de tu variable `out_c`:

```
void reservar( float **out_c, int bands ) {
  cudaMalloc( out_c, bands*sizeof( float ) );
  check_CUDA_Error( "ERROR EN cudaMalloc de out_c" );
}
```

Y vamos a cambiar también la forma en la que las estás llamando: pasaremos directamente la dirección de tu variable:

```
reservar( &out_c, bands );
copiar( out_c, v , bands );
```

Listo.

Comment: Es perfecto, muchas gracias :´)